# "Beautify" Brackets Equivalent for Visual Studio IDE

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I've got a question. As **Brackets** WebDev IDE has its plugin called **Beautify** to clean up the syntax, make it more readable, is there some Visual studio Package with such function?

Every answer matters :)
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about an extension as such, but if you press `Ctrl`+`K` and then `Ctrl`+`F` in sequence it will auto-indent your code for you. I believe the style of auto indentation you want can be configured in the Settings pane.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i was asking for. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! :)